# How to get href value and make it as a javascript variable?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a list of link like this:

```
<li><a href="landing.php?products=IPCamera&id=1">IP Camera 1</a></li>
<li><a href="landing.php?products=IPCamera&id=2">IP Camera 2</a></li>
<li><a href="landing.php?products=CCTVCamera&id=1">CCTV 1</a></li>
```

and the following sample php code:

```
// PRODUCTS AND ID IS DYNAMICALLY PRODUCE FROM PHP QUERY
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename";
$result = mysql_query($sql); //
foreach($result as $field) {
   $listlink = "landing.php?products=".$field[products]."&id"=$field[id];
   $output = "<li><a href=\"$listlink\">".$field[menuname]."</a></li>";
}
echo $output; // THIS IS THE RESULT OF LIST OF LINK ABOVE
```

My question is how to make the value of products and id to become a javascript variable and pass it to a jquery ajax to call a php processor.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use data attributes and access them via jquery by using the jQuery.data() function.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename";
$result = mysql_query($sql); //
foreach($result as $field) {
   $listlink = "landing.php?products=".$field[products]."&id"=$field[id];
   $output = "<li><a data-products=\"$field[products]\" data-id=\"$field[id]\"  href=\"$listlink\">".$field[menuname]."</a></li>";
}
```

the js part will be like this

```
$("a").click(function() {
   var id = $(this).data('id');
   var products = $(this).data('products');
   var url = $(this).attr('href');

   // your ajax request goes here
});
```

Comment: Nice and clean, no regexp needed for this one. Good job!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `location.search` to get the query part of the current location and then extract the field to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about code running on this `products.php` page based on the `products` and `id` in the URL:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var params = {}, queryString = location.search.substring(1),
    re = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g, m;

while (m = re.exec(queryString)) {
    params[decodeURIComponent(m[1])] = decodeURIComponent(m[2]);
}

//now params is an object containing all the query string parameters from the URL
do_your_ajax_thing(params[id], params[products]);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the values of products column in a row in PHP and then use json_encode() to send the array json encoded to javascript.
Just an example how to do this.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var productValueArray = <?php

               $outputArray = array();
               $sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename";
               $result = mysql_query($sql); //
               foreach($result as $field) {
                  array_push($outputArray, $field[menuname]);
               }
               echo json_encode($outputArray);

                        ?>

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var urlArgs = location.search,
    products = urlArgs.substring(urlArgs.indexOf("=") + 1, urlArgs.indexOf("&")),
```

and for id also you can use substring() or split() method and do the string manipulation.